# Running emacs in batch mode from command line doesn't work

Tags: org-mode, org-export, doom, batch-mode

Does anyone know if ox-koma-export.el can be invoked from command line:

```sh
emacs --batch -e '(org-koma-letter-export-to-pdf)' letter.org
```

Should emacs in general be universally reproducible from command line? Or am I trying to do something strange? I expected this to produce a PDF file.

I've tried this as well, but it yields the same error:

```
emacs --batch -e '(progn (find-file "letter.org") (org-koma-letter-export-to-pdf))'
```

Answer (score 0):

My bad, there is no `-e` option, no `-b` option and the file needs to be the second argument. This works:

```sh
emacs letter.org --batch --eval '(org-koma-letter-export-to-pdf)'
```

Found out by [RTFM](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/BatchMode#h5o-1) (I mixed up emacs and emacsclient).

Comment: “*there is no `-e` option, no `-b` option*” - Emm... Did you try `-h`?

Comment: @shynur: `emacs -h` gives me an error and the single letter options that the OP mentions don't work for me either. They are also not mentioned on the man page or in Info (at least for current upstream). Are you talking about `emacsclient` perhaps?

Comment: @NickD yes, sorry. I mixed them up.

Comment: @DanielKrajnik: I don't think you mixed them up (or else I'm all mixed up). AFAICT, `emacs` requires `--eval` and it will not accept `-e` in its place. `emacsclient` will accept either.